# Why Doesn't ng-repeat work inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something very simple in AngularJS but just can't seem to get it working.

I have a directive and I place some HTML inside the directive that uses ng-repeat on an array inside the directive scope. The problem is that the looping variable is undefined despite it iterating the number of elements in the array.

I know this because I print the element it is currently on in the loop and it prints "undefined", but prints it the number of elements in the array.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Branches</p>
   <ul>
    <showbranch>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Name
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="subBranch in subBranches"
      <td>
        {{ f(subBranch.label) }}
      </td>
      </showbranch>
  </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  treeBranch = function(){};
  $scope.branch = new treeBranch();
$scope.branch.label = "Main Branch";

var subBranch1 = new treeBranch(); subBranch1.label = "branch 1";
var subBranch2 = new treeBranch(); subBranch2.label = "branch 2";
var subBranch3 = new treeBranch(); subBranch3.label = "branch 3";

$scope.branch.subBranches = [ subBranch1, subBranch2, subBranch3 ];

});

app.directive('showbranch',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',

    link:function(scope,element,attrs)
    {
      console.log("Attr: ", attrs);
      console.log(scope);
      scope.subBranches = scope.branch.subBranches;
      scope.f = function(e){
        console.log(e)
        return e
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a plunkr of the code:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/5uf6TcT0xqkl7TVe

Comment: That html structure is not valid. `<ul>` only accepts `<li>` as children and `<tr>` must be within valid table elements like `<table>`, `<tbody>` etc

Comment: You're right. I updated the directive to have a table template. Although I'm not sure it will create a valid table. I originally wanted to find out if it was possible to add HTML in between directive tags when I encountered this problem.

Comment: Need to start with valid structure first. You also added `transclude` without using `ng-transclude`

Comment: If you are going to edit the code in the question, be sure to update the PLNKR.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid, that's why you don't see all the elements.

Inside the `ul` you must show the elements as list elements, and not as tr elements, otherwise it will show up just one single child.

Then your logic is not the best one in angularjs mind.

If you have a directive called `showBranch` most probably that should be responsible for showing a single branch, given as scope parameter.

And there is no need to return functions to make it dynamic, simply provide it as scope parameter.

So your example could be something like the following:

```
app.directive('showbranch',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      branch: '='
    },
    template: '<div>NAME: {{branch.label}}</div>'
  }
})
```

And

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="subBranch in branch.subBranches track by $index">
    <showbranch branch="subBranch" ></showbranch>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just wanted log exactly what was going on in the loop so that was the point of the function. Is there a way of adding HTML in between the directive tags without specifying it in the template?

Comment: what you are asking about the HTML is a bit odd. What do you mean? You want do dynamically inject HTML? yeah that's possible, but again, sometimes you are over complicating something that angularjs makes easier. 

About the loggin what was going on, if you create your `link` function and put a plain `console.log` there, it will be logged automatically when the directive is linked

Comment: Small correction, angular [doesn't care](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ6fZFLiKjCykQLax3cC?p=preview) about the markup.  You can repeat `<main>` in a `<ul>` for all it cares.

Comment: @Phix not at all. Angular doesn't care, but angular produces HTML as output. If you put tr elements inside ul, it will display only one element. You can easily check it with this code: `<ul>
    <tr ng-repeat="subBranch in branch.subBranches track by $index">
      <showbranch branch="subBranch" ></showbranch>
    </tr>
  </ul>`

Comment: @Phix it's how the browser handles invalid markup that matters. Some are more tolerant than others

Comment: @charlietfl exactly what I meant with "angular then produces HTML as output". If it produces some not valid HTML, it won't work anyway, even if angular worked fine

Comment: and let me add that even if the browsers will "fix" your invalid HTML, that's not a good reason to have/produce invalid HTMl

Comment: Maybe I'm not going about what I want to do correctly. Essentially I wanted to create a directive that replaces the <table> tag so that I could still write the rows and headers in the html itself, but with my own table directive.

Comment: so maybe you want a `showBranches` directive which directly shows up the table with all the elements?

Comment: Not all the tables I would create with this directive would have the same HTML in the rows though. Like if I wanted to add a button for a row in one table, but not all the tables, then I wouldn't be able to do that if I specified the html in the template of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

The `<tr>` element does not repeat because the browser is removing bad HTML as the parent element is not a `<table>`.

The solution is to add a `<table>` element to make it valid HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Branches</p>
   <ul>
    <showbranch>
      <!-- ADD table ELEMENT HERE -->
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Name
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="subBranch in subBranches">
      <td>
        {{ f(subBranch.label) }}
      </td>
      </table>
      </showbranch>
  </ul>
  </body>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/HO2fMSPoncSV6oLNu4UY?preview&p=preview)